# Button moves when adding multiple line text

Tags: android, button, text, multiline

I'm trying to add multiple lines of text to a button but when trying the answers from this question:

["https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103776/how-can-i-display-multiple-lines-of-text-on-a-button/8103880#8103880"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103776/how-can-i-display-multiple-lines-of-text-on-a-button/8103880#8103880)

My button moves down, or adds a margin above itself. Any ideas why?

Comment: What do you mean by 'it moves down'? In relation to what?

Comment: If you have 3 buttons lined up together vertically, the one's that contain enough text to wrap to a 2nd line will be displaced by about 16dp downwards, for no reason

Answer (score 21):

Try to set `android:baselineAligned="false"` in layout where button is placed.

Check this topic also: [Alignment issues with two-line button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918138/alignment-issues-with-two-line-button).

Comment: One of my buttons is 2 lines of text when viewed in a language other than english and the button kept moving up on the screen for multi-line text.  I added android:baselineAligned="false" to the LinearLayout it was in and it's fixed - THANK YOU!  This should be marked as the answer.